# NextJS - Robots.txt is not shown

Tags: next.js

I've added 'robots.txt' under /public folder.
It works on localhost (on npm run dev and npm run build).

But when I send it to server, it returns 404 not found error.
I can see other files inside /public files, but can not see robots.txt

What can be wrong with it?

Comment: Don't you have robots.txt in your .gitignore file?

Comment: no, I dont have. And when I download project from the server, so I can see 'robots.txt' in public folder. But It doesnt work. Couldnt understand why.